# How to create a Log Files in Unity3D Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Greeting,

Currently I having some issues with my client side where their devices is having issues with my app, but they located outside of my country and I can't reach them.

Is there anyway to create a log files when the app is running or crashes? So they can send me the log files so I can fix the issues.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use analytics and send usage data there.